# Longtable in LaTex: spacing between /caption*{} and table

Tags: spacing, captions, longtable

I inserted a note to my longtable in LaTeX with `\caption*{tablenote}`. This works fine but I am wondering how you can reduce the spacing between the note and the table, like `\vspace*{-1cm}` or similar?

My code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,abstract=true,a4paper,toc=bib]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
{\footnotesize
\begin{longtable}{l c c c c c}
\caption{... \label{descstat1}}\\
\toprule\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Variable}}
 &\textbf{Mean}
 & \textbf{Std. Dev.}& \textbf{Min.} &  \textbf{Max.} & \textbf{N} \\ 
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{6}{l}{Table \thetable, continued}
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{r}{Continued on following page...}\\
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
\textit{Dependent variables} &&&&&\\
1 & a & b & c & d & e\\
...
\caption*{\footnotesize ...}
\end{longtable}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a negative skip with the optional argument of `\addlinespace`, from `booktabs`, or you can use the `ThreePartTablex` package, which defines a `TableNotes` environment for `longtable`s.

Here is an illustration of both methods:

```
\documentclass[12pt,abstract=true,a4paper,toc=bib]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable, caption, threeparttablex}

\begin{document}
  {\footnotesize
\begin{longtable}{l c c c c c}
\caption{... \label{descstat1}}\\
\addlinespace
\toprule\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Variable}}
 &\textbf{Mean}
 & \textbf{Std. Dev.}& \textbf{Min.} & \textbf{Max.} & \textbf{N} \\
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{6}{l}{Table \thetable, continued}\\
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{r}{Continued on following page...}\\
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\addlinespace[-1.5ex]
\caption*{\footnotesize ...}
\endlastfoot
\textit{Dependent variables} &&&&&\\
1 & a & b & c & d & e\\
...
\end{longtable}}


  \begin{ThreePartTable}
  \footnotesize
    \begin{TableNotes}
    \item[]\hspace*{-1.2em} ………
    \end{TableNotes}
\begin{longtable}{l c c c c c}
\caption{... \label{descstat2}}\\
\addlinespace\toprule%\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Variable}}
 &\textbf{Mean}
 & \textbf{Std. Dev.}& \textbf{Min.} & \textbf{Max.} & \textbf{N} \\
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{6}{l}{Table \thetable, continued}\\
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{r}{Continued on following page...}\\
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot
\textit{Dependent variables} &&&&&\\
1 & a & b & c & d & e\\
...
\end{longtable}
  \end{ThreePartTable}


\end{document}
```

[image]